# Reading and updating multiple tabs in the same spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet where I retrieve data using the Google Analytics addon. In a tab I combine all the data and use this specific tab for my Google Datastudio report. In here I analyze my Google Ads campaign data - the costs and the conversions.

This Spreadsheet has multiple tabs (each tab contains a specific conversion) I need to be able to read and write for multiple tabs. It has to read the Google Analytics data and write this data in another sheet.
I originally created this script to read from 1 tab and to write to 1 tab and it was working. Then I noticed I will need to do this for almost all the tabs.

This is my current script:

```
function readAndWrite() {
    var spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
    var counter = 0;
    var rangeName = ['readingTab1!A16:C','readingTab2!A16:C','readingTab3!A16:C','readingTab4!A16:C','readingTab5!A16:C'];
    var rangePush = ['writingTab1','writingTab2','writingTab3','writingTab4','writingTab5','writingTab5'];
    var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName[counter]).values;
    var data = [];
  
    if (!values) {
      Logger.log('No data found.');
    } else {
      Logger.log('Starting script.');
      Logger.log('There are ' + values.length + ' unique rows.');
      Logger.log(values[0][2]);

while (counter < 5){
  data.length = 0;

  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
      var campaign = values[row][0];
      var date = values[row][1];
      var cost = values[row][2];
      data.push({range: rangePush[counter], values: [[date, campaign, cost]]});
      }
counter++;
    
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"},spreadsheetId);
    }
    
    }
    Logger.log('Finished.');
    
}
```

In the rangeName I have created an array with the names and ranges of my tab where it should read from.
In the rangePush I created an array with the names where it should push the data to.

When I run the script I receive the following error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid data[1886]: Unable to parse range: writingTab2.

Is there anyone who can see what is going wrong and able to help me out here?
I hope my explanation is clear, if not please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue of `API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid data[1886]: Unable to parse range: writingTab2.`. In order to correctly replicate your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, here is the spreadsheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1stblfOevl26mawFgq4yhAOsoz6HEXCMxLng9Wl7XJtg/edit#gid=0.  Now the initial error message is not there but I'm getting another error, GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid data[0]: ValueRange.range is required but not specified.
If you can point me in the right direction what I need to fix t hat would be great!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, thanks for your quick reply. I changed the sharing settings of the spreadsheet. Now you should be able to open it. Can you please check?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirim it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from `readingTab#!A16:C` sheet to `writingTab#` sheet using Sheets API with Google Apps Script.

  - Those sheet names are put to the arrays and each index of both is corresponding to the copy and paste sheets.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

At first, about your error, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, there are 3 read and write sheets of `'readingTab1!A16:C', 'readingTab2!A16:C', 'readingTab3!A16:C'` and `'writingTab1', 'writingTab2', 'writingTab3'`. But your script uses `while (counter < 5){`. By this, the range becomes `undefined` after `counter` is more than 4. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

In order to achieve your goal by removing this issue, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

When `spreadsheets.values.batchGet` and `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` methods are used, the script becomes the following simple script.

```js
function readAndWrite() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
  var rangeName = ['readingTab1!A16:C', 'readingTab2!A16:C', 'readingTab3!A16:C'];
  var rangePush = ['writingTab1', 'writingTab2', 'writingTab3'];

  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(spreadsheetId, {ranges: rangeName}).valueRanges;
  values.forEach((v, i) => v.range = rangePush[i]);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data: values, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- In this modified script, it supposes that there are 3 read and write sheets of `'readingTab1!A16:C', 'readingTab2!A16:C', 'readingTab3!A16:C'` and `'writingTab1', 'writingTab2', 'writingTab3'`. When you add more sheets, please add them to the arrays of `rangeName` and `rangePush`.

#### Note:

- **In this script, please check the values of `rangeName` and `rangePush` and the sheet names of your Spreadsheet again.**
- This script uses Sheets API. So, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.
- I think that in your situation, the Spreadsheet service instead of Sheets API can also achieve your goal. But I think that the process cost will be lower when Sheets API is used. But, when you want to achieve your goal without using Sheets API, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function readAndWrite2() {
      var spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
      var rangeName = ['readingTab1!A16:C', 'readingTab2!A16:C', 'readingTab3!A16:C'];
      var rangePush = ['writingTab1', 'writingTab2', 'writingTab3'];

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
      rangeName.forEach((r, i) => ss.getRange(r).copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(rangePush[i]).getRange("A1")));
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, your first solution is working perfectly for what I need! Thank you very much for your help, your detailed answer and your solution. Amazing!

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, I accepted your answer as the solution! Thank you again for your time and help.